# How to pass selected by querySelector element into a function in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function changeColor(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("Color has changed!");
}

docuement.querySelector(".box").addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

How i can pass my selected ".box" element as argument into a listener function of addEventListener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is passed as an argument to `changeColor()` and you can access the target element with `event.target`.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target